# How to access WSO2 BAM's hadoop job tracker?

Tags: hadoop, hive, wso2, wso2-bam

I am quite new to BAM and one of my hive queries is broken.
However I can't find what's wrong since the only error it gives me is

> ERROR: Error while executing Hive script.Query returned non-zero code: 9, cause: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask

I've looked around and found out that BAM is only capable of displaying that much information and for more I need to look in hadoop's job tracker. However I can't find any info on how to turn it on or access it in the BAM server.
So how do I access it/ turn it on ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do not mislead with the exception. Most probably this seems to be a problem with Hive query. To get a proper idea about the problem you should send the backend console print log.

Comment: The one in the repository/logs directory ? That one shows the exact same error

Comment: Yes. It will have more details. Anyway you better try with an existing example to see whether your setup is working properly. If yes you have to figure out the problem in your Hive script.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the problem is most probably with your hive query and not with hadoop job tracker. To make sure, please run of the samples[1] and check whether hive queries are executing properly. If hive queries executing without a problem and summarized results are displayed in dashboards, the problem could be with your hive query.

[1] - http://docs.wso2.org/display/BAM240/HTTPD+Logs+Analysis+Sample

Comment: I know the problem is with my query. What i want to know is how can i view more specific errors instead of this 1 generic error that it gives me every time

Comment: Full exception stack trace logged in back-end wso2carbon.log can be helpful in-order to identify the error.